# Alias Substitution in Fish Shell

Tags: bash, fish

**Question:** Is there a Fish equivalent of Bash's alias substitution or what's the recommended best practice to keep the code clean and DRY?

**Background:** There's a very useful feature of aliases in Bash called alias substitution. It's mentioned briefly in the man page:

```
alias [-p] [name[=value] ...]
    ...
    A trailing space in value causes the next word to be checked for alias substitution when the alias is expanded.
    ...
```

The power of this functionality may easily be conveyed with an example. Consider that many users define a grep alias. Here's mine:

```
# extended regex, skip binaries, devices, sockets, & dirs, colored, & line
# -buffered. use a non- canonical alias instead of GREP_OPTIONS which may wreck
# poorly written scripts
alias g='grep -EID skip -d skip --color=auto --line-buffered'
```

Similarly, many of those same users define an alias for xargs. Here's mine **without** alias substitution:

```
alias x='xargs -rd\\n' # \n delimited, don't run on empty in
```

And finally, here's how I might want to use it but it doesn't work:

```
$ find|x g foo
xargs: g: No such file or directory
```

This command fails because x is expanded to xargs and it can't find an executable called `g`. There are a number of workarounds for this but I think most are awful. However, by just adding a trailing space, the shell will perform alias substitution on our behalf and the command will work as intended:

```
alias x='xargs -rd\\n ' # \n delimited, don't run on empty in, + expansion
#                    ^-- this space is for expanding a subsequent alias
```

Please keep in mind that this is **just an example**, not necessarily the actual use case.

**Update 2015-05-06**

I never found a Fishism solution but I felt the alternative was worth a comment. I took the approach of creating shell scripts in `~/bin`. The downsides are:

- The shell configuration is now multiple files.
- The interpreter loses inspection of otherwise simple aliases and functions.

However, I felt the upsides were pretty huge:

- The scripts may be written in any language.
- The scripts are completely independent of the shell choice. Trying new shells is extremely painless. It's been a joy to have a single prompt script that doesn't have to be rewritten or maintained in multiple languages.

Comment: First reaction: [no](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#alias). Next reaction: since fish aliases are just functions in disguise, you can create an `xg` function to combine the bash `x` and `g` aliases.

Comment: @glennjackman when you say combine, do you mean `function xg; xargs -rd\\n grep -EID skip -d skip --color=auto --line-buffered $argv; end`? This is exactly what I want to avoid since I'd need to define the "`g`" and `x` functionalities in two places each, `g`, `xg`, `x`.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. fish has no equivalent to bash's alias substitution (or zsh's global aliases), so I don't think you have much of a choice. I suppose you could say something like `function x; xargs -rd\\n fish -c "$argv"; end`, but that's likely full of pitfalls

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks, that's one of the Bash workarounds I want to avoid using. I think I'll stick a silly "g" script in my path instead.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a Fish based solution -- but I suspect the fish answer is going to be *it's not possible*.

You could create your aliases as `.fish` or `.sh` scripts and symlink them to `/usr/local/bin` -- this will give you the equivalent behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, this is a workaround I'm currently using, save I'm using `~/bin` instead, but it's not without drawbacks.